# Adobe Illustrator: Is possible to build an impossible 3D-shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, 3d, research

Would it be possible to build this "impossible" shape as a 3-dimensional object in Illustrator?

[image: ImpossibleShape]
[image: ImpossibleShape_Rotated]

[image: ImpossibleShape_Animated]

(Image Source: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj77fu2EcKg))

So far I have only been able to create a 2-dimensional version (which obviously is quite easy in Illustrator), not rotatable like the one in the example above:

[image: 2-dimensional-sketch]
[image: 2-dimensional-sketch_rotated]

Do Illustrator's 3D-capabilities allow for the creation of an actual 3D-version of such a shape?

Comment: What 3D capabilties are you talking about? The only one I know is Extrude, and no, that one cannot create impossible objects out of a flat original drawing.

Comment: Well, with things like Effect -> 3D -> Revolve its at least possible to create some basic 3D shapes such as a sphere out of semicircle. I was simply wondering whether there's any way for me to get a rotatable version of this shape in Illustrator. Does Photoshop offer any solutions for this? Or do I have to shoot for something like Blender?

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda an oxymoron. No 3D modeling software can build an impossible shape, that's why its impossible. It exists using perspective tricks / illusions of representing a three dimensional object on a two dimensional plane. It can't exist in real life or be modeled to actually be that shape. The closest is changing the model as the angle of view changes. Blender, AutoCAD, Maya, it doesn't matter.

There's another question on this topic on Gaming StackExchange that might be of interest to you as well - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56230/is-the-impossible-object-possible-in-computer-graphics

Comment: Very true, of course what I am trying to create is only a 3D-shape representing this type of illusion. I was basically wondering whether the shape seen in the .gif (which is precisely what you mentioned, an illusion of something physically impossible) could be done in Illustrator, rotatable and all. Due me not having any knowledge of 3D-tools (Blender, etc.) I was looking for an alternative, since I will only be needing a 2D-picture of the shape for a print project. But if there's no way around an actual 3D-model then I guess its time for me to broaden my horizon.

Comment: Well yes, however that does not mean that the object can not be projected to the camera that way ;)